# Как запустить все микросервисы одной командой в nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs, микросервисы

У меня есть backend написанный с использованием микросервисного подхода. Внутри есть 5 микросервисов. Каждый микросервис приходится запускать вручную в отдельном терминале. Я пытался найти решение этой проблемы в документации nestjs, нашел только `app.startAllMicroservices()` , но оно, несмотря на название, не делает то что мне нужно. Пытался найти как запустить сразу несколько приложений через одну команду в `npm` , но ничего не нашел